# Spring Kafka -Consumer seek aware methods not invoked

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am implementing `ConsumerSeekAware` in my listener class. But overridden methods registerSeekCallback,onPartitionsAssigned,onIdleContainer never get invoked. Below are my consumer config and consumer files.
Could not identify the mistake.

using Spring-kafka : 1.1.6 version.

Consumer:

```java
package com.test.kafka.binder;

import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerSeekAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Consumer implements ConsumerSeekAware {
    
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}", group = "foo")
  public void listen(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received Messasge in group foo: " + message);
  }
    
  @Override
  public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    System.out.println("registerSeekCallback");
  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    System.out.println("onPartitionsAssigned");
  }
    
  @Override
  public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    System.out.println("onIdleContainer");
  }
}
```

Consumer Config:

```
package com.test.kafka.binder;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
 

     @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
     private Object bootstrapAddress;

     
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
          bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, 
          "test");
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
 
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
      kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
          = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging; if you can't figure it out from that, post the logs someplace.

Comment: @GrayRussell Could not find from spring-kafka debug logs. Logs shared here => http://text-share.com/view/a46d764a

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known problem](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/403) it is fixed on master. We need to release 1.1.7.

However, if you can upgrade to 1.2.1, it's already fixed there.

Note that you also need to enable idle events:

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(10_000L);
```